# Probability of getting back to the starting point - Part 2 (unequal probabilities)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Points A, B and C lie on a circle and are arranged in clockwise order. We roll a fair 6-sided die and perform any of the 3 following operations based on the roll of the die.

- Move Clockwise - if 1 or 2 shows up.
- Move Anti-Clockwise - if 3 or 4 shows up.
- Do not move - if 5 or 6 show up.

We take A as our starting point. We roll the dice 8 times and perform the operations based on the dice roll.
What is the probability that we end up getting back to A.
[This is how A, B & C lie on the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig3wG.png)

I was able to [solve this question with some help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200483/probability-of-getting-back-to-the-starting-point).

I wanted to add some twists to the problem statement and came up with assigning different probabilities to the operations -

```
We pick and choose the operations at random instaad of the dice roll -

 - There is a 2/6 chance of selecting the Clockwise Operation
 - There is a 3/6 chance of selecting the Anti-Clockwise Operation
 - There is a 1/6 chance of not moving at all (No Movement Operation)
```

Now, what is the probability that we end up getting back to A.

I was able to pinpoint all the valid states in the [previously asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200483/probability-of-getting-back-to-the-starting-point).

As all the operations were equally likely before, we could use combinatorics to calculate all valid states and divide it by the total number of states to get the answer.

Here, I assigned probabilities to each of the valid states. For example -

P({2, 2, 4}) = $(2/6)^2 * (3/6)^2 * (1/6)^4$  - (as the events are independent)
and then added all of them.

However, I strongly believe my approach is incorrect. If I use the same approach on the unmodified version of the problem, I would reach the wrong answer i.e $15 * (1/3)^8$.

How should one approach this problem ? I believe this is related to Markov Chains but still unsure on the procedure.

Comment: $P(\{2,2,4\})=\frac{8!}{2!2!4!}*(2/6)^2 * (3/6)^2 * (1/6)^4$ accounting for the number of ways you can obtain $\{2,2,4\}$

Comment: The actual answer is going to be close to $\dfrac13$ and is in fact $\dfrac13+\dfrac{1}{746496} \approx 0.333334673$.  If you want to use Markov Chains then write down the transition matrix and raise it to the $10$th power